# Mysql DISTINCT and ORDER BY not working

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by, distinct

I have this query:

```
    SELECT
  DISTINCT (entries.guid),
  locales.*,
  locales.guid as locale_guid,
  entries.*,
  node.category_guid,
  node.title as node_title,
  nodelocs.caption as node_caption,
  nodelocs.uri as node_uri,
  nodelocs.url as node_url
FROM entries AS entries
  JOIN entry_locales AS locales ON (locales.entry_guid=entries.guid)
  LEFT JOIN nodes AS node ON (node.guid=entries.node_guid)
  LEFT JOIN node_locales AS nodelocs ON (nodelocs.node_guid=entries.node_guid AND nodelocs.lang_guid=locales.lang_guid)

  LEFT JOIN metrics as metrics_default ON (entries.guid = metrics_default.entry_guid)
WHERE

  metrics_default.customer_guid='453b894967968204'

  AND metrics_default.metrics='entryview'

  AND locales.lang_guid='4b5747548a5bd457'

  AND locales.state='1' AND entries.node_guid IN  (SELECT child_guid FROM node_children WHERE guid IN ('4b084f280caffbef') )  ORDER BY metrics_default._updated DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

So I want to get items with unique guids and want to order it by '_updated' field from 'metricts_default' table. But nothing happens.
If I delete DISTINCT() - result is fine, but with duplicates.

Comment: distinct is not a function on a column. It applies to all columns being selected.

Answer (score 1):

you misunderstand the distinct
keyword **distinct** here does not mean you will get distinct entries.guid, but **different row**

what this mean is the row with same guid but different In other fields will not be eliminated by MySQL.

Comment: oh...Can you tell me please, how can I get only rows grouped by entries.guid and with order by 'metrics_default._updated'?

Comment: I think you can do it easily in a programming language like Python after you get the rows from MySQL.